# Optimal Fuel for GyroJet Handheld Weapon?

Tags: weapons, hard-science, firearms

Is there optimal fuel for gyrojet weapons?

Specifically, what fuel would best propel gyrojets from a hand held launcher (read gun -- ex: pistol, rifle, volley gun, etc.)?  I'm looking for velocity -- however, how dangerous would this fuel be? Comparisons based on cost and corrosion / toxicity would be helpful.

Ammunition could vary between .22 and .969 calibers.

Lethality is the central goal.

Comment: It seems like you're wanting to start another open-ended discussion about an unbounded list of potential options, without providing any guidance about how to balance, energy, cost, many different safety considerations, or other factors you want to consider in your optimal "fuel". In general asking for a superlative such as most, least, or optimal, tends to leave a question underspecified.

Comment: Please provide some metrics by which "optimal" can be judged. For example, I shall propose antimatter. A couple of grams of antilithium propellant in a hand-held firearm will provide excellent guarantees of lethality at normal engagement ranges, even when faced with heavily armored targets, or targets behind substantial cover. There are tradeoffs, of course, but the question as stands doesn't seem to care about those...

Answer (score 2):

**ALICE**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALICE_(propellant)

ALICE is nano aluminum particles and H2O ice.  Once ignited the aluminum strips oxygen from water to burn.  Hydrogen gas is produced from the water and the  expanding hot hydrogen provides propulsion.

> The oxide layer in nano-aluminum powder, however, is thinner and
> easier to overcome than in that of larger particles. This makes the
> combustion of aluminum with water ice easier to ignite and sustain.
> Furthermore, as the aluminum consumes the oxygen, it liberates
> hydrogen which functions as a low molecular mass working fluid to
> translate the heat of combustion (and subsequently condensation) into
> expansion and thrust. The high density of the mixture allows for
> reduced tankage mass and high thrust.
>
> The base combustion reaction is:[1]
>
> 2 Al + 3 H2O → Al2O3 + 3 H2

Your ALICE propelled bullets must be kept cold.  Possibly in a thermos.    There could be ice cream in the same thermos and you would need to lick bullets clean before firing.  These bullets are unlikely to go off accidentally because this is not a conventional explosive.  The ignition method is fiddly but it is built into the guns and "fiddly" is OK for an Englishman.

It is possible that these bullets might leave a trail of flame, with the hot hydrogen and entrained glowing aluminum oxide burning in air.  Trails of flame are OK for some applications (e.g. you need to be awesome) and less so for others (e.g. you are hiding and do not want trails of flame pointing at your hiding place).

Comment: What flavour ice cream though?

Comment: That no flavor ice cream.  I have it on good authority you can get that in the UK.

Comment: [I can attest to this.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/117144/52367) There used to be a really long argument below that answer but I guess the food police deleted it for being too divisive.